# JS Code over AJAX with jQuery - is this method safe?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have an AJAX call that returns a HTML snippet that needs to be injected to the page, as well as some JS code under a 'script' element.

There are no html/body/head elements in the response, just the HTML that needs to be injected. so the response could be:

```
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
<script>alert(1);</script>
```

From my understanding, JS code that was fetched via AJAX needs to be added to the page by either using eval() or by creating a  element, i.e.:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.text = response;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.appendChild(script);
```

But, I've tried embedding the response as is, using .html() in jQuery - and to my surprise, it seems that both the JS code and the HTML part, were handled as expected, the HTML part was added to the page, and the JS code ran just fine.

this is what I've tried:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#foo').html(data);
        // #foo now contains '<div>lorem ipsum</div>' and the JS alert was fired
    }
});
```

Is this a safe method? will it work on every browser?

If it's not - what would be the best way to accomplish what I'm trying (I'll probably have to parse the response to separate the `<script>` elements from the rest) ?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Well, two problems, first that isn't the best solution (and could break on browsers), and second if that code is anything but hard coded (and even then), it is way to easy to create an xss breach.  If either the ajax'd html or the url is changeable, you are in for some headaches.

Basically put, I don't recommend it, I would look for an alternate solution.

Comment: I agree - you don't want the user having access to programatically affecting your code. Better to, for instance, call your own pre-written function as a callback based on the response you get rather than evaling a code received over the wires. Also, you could go more lightweight and receive the content as JSON, then build the HTML snippet for insert, instead of sending full HTML content over ajax.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's .html() function uses innerHTML and IE requires the DEFER attribute to be set on scripts loaded this way or they won't execute. I think the createElement method is a better approach.

Going further, my opinion is that it's better to transmit only JSON and avoid eval-ing dynamic Javascript. You can then parse the response with JSON.parse and client-side code can do whatever is necessary with this data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to do could be accomplished by JSON-P.

Basically, instead of making an XHR call, you dynamically create a script element whose SRC attribute points to the URL you want to load. The server would then return the following:

```
$('<div>foo</div>').appendTo('#bar');
alert(1);
```

The upside is that you can make JSON-P calls cross domain. The downside is that you can still open yourself up to XSS attacks. But honestly, that's always an issue no matter what you do. As long as you dot your Is and cross your Ts, I think it's OK to do either option.

In order to offer a non-eval/SCRIPT option, can you describe the nature of the follow-on JS code you are trying to execute?